# What is a good alternative to DBAmp for users on an Oracle Database?

Tags: tools

I'm familiar and happy with the DBAmp product (http://www.forceamp.com/) that replicates data between MS-SQL and Salesforce.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a tool that they have used successfully for doing the same thing in an Oracle environment (or for that matter, non MS-SQL).

I know this stuff could be built using an ETL tool, but I am not seeking a  I'm more interested in a tool specifically dedicated to this kind of relational <--> sf replication.

Comment: I don't think it's a good question, all kinds of advertisements will pop up... Having said that - I'm not related to companies I'm going to mention, etc etc... Check out partner products, AppExchange should be a good start. Informatica (on Demand) should be OK? My colleague did some amazing things in data migration part of the project with a tool called Relational Junction (mind it was back in 2008, no idea how the tool is like now). But really anything that will have "Salesforce to ODBC adapter" in features should be a good start?

Comment: How do I make it a 'good question' when my actual requirement is 'I'm looking for a product'?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a good answer to it ;) it's just http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88/is-this-question-a-good-candidate-to-downvote and http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95/are-questions-about-apps-in-the-app-exchange-off-topic raise some interesting points... Maybe on a chat? IRC channel? Besides - don't worry, it's just me, nobody clicked the "close" link yet so maybe I'm overreacting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Oracle integration, but I know it's been done (specifically with Informatica and Cast Iron). Here's a list of [integration services](http://www.salesforce.com/platform/cloud-infrastructure/integration.jsp) for use with Salesforce.

1. [Informatica Cloud](http://www.informaticacloud.com/)
2. [IBM Cast Iron Cloud](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/cast-iron-cloud-integration/)
3. [SnapLogic](http://www.snaplogic.com/what-we-do/integration-platform/)
4. [Dell Boomi](http://www.boomi.com/)
5. [Pervasive Datacloud](http://cloud.pervasive.com/)
6. [JitterBit](http://www.jitterbit.com/)
7. [Sesame Relational Junction](http://www.sesamesoftware.com/rj4salesforce.html)
8. [DBAmp](http://www.forceamp.com/)

Also, here's some information on other tools, to integrate Salesforce with databases that may be helpful:

1. [Salesforce Web Services API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm)
2. [Salesforce Bulk API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index.htm)
3. [Salesforce Rest API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm)

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a tool which handles the replication in a 'hands free manner', mainly automatically backing up the SF data, including schema changes.  Not a general ETL tool like Boomi which is going to require me to build maps for each object I'm storing.  However, you mention Relational Junction which fits the requirement's I'm seeking.

Answer (score 2):

i have used Rational junction during my days at one of the largest salesforce org. in the ecosystem to mirror millions of records from salesforce instances (PROD, UAT, TEST, STAGING, DEV) to Database (including terradata, Oracle, MS-SQL, you name it)

The best thing was running simple commands such as -getall, -getsobject, etc. to get the metadata definition (both from scratch as well as incremental) to the database, without grunt work of creating the table/columns in DB. heck it also gets you the incremental  columns for the existing row in the destination DB. It also respects the relationship between various sobjects, as well as self relationships (automatically for most part).

Using Rational Junction, we mirrored a Production org. to a make a duplicate Production org. (in the case of divestiture) especially for the metadata.

It definitely has lot of pros.

Cons-

1. Cost, I heard it was very expensive.
2. The web user interface was meh...
3. For some reason it didn't support formula fields. So the back up data had all the columns except for formula fields
4. Support is ok (for the money we spent)
5. We ran into issues such Boolean tranformations, truncations etc. during POC and testing. It took a while to resolve such issues. Once the interface was up and running, never faced any problems.

Steve, I know the timing of my response it off, hope it helps the community.